# Fitting a multilevel model to data from an experiment with between- and within-subjects factors

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have data from an experiment that I would like to analyse with a multilevel model. In the experiment, participants read 1 scenario about a person and they had to answer a couple of questions about this scenario.

The content of the scenario was determined by two between-subjects factors: income (high, low, neutral) + behavior (good, bad). Those two factors were fully crossed, resulting in 6 cells. Participants were randomly assigned to one of the 6 cells.

Participants had to answer three questions about the same scenario: how much do you like the behavior in the scenario ; how much do you think others like the behavior in this scenario ; how much do you think the person in the scenario likes his/her own behavior. Participants answered on a 7 point scale ranging from 'not at all' to 'very much' So, this would constitute another factor, let's call it 'perspective', with three levels: self, others, thirdperson.

To recapitulate: two between-subjects fixed factors, income and behavior, fully crossed; participants are nested within income*behavior cell; 1 scenario per income*behavior cell; each participant answers 3 questions about the scenario they are assigned to.

I am interested in the three-way interaction between income, behavior, and perspective.

**I am struggling with building the correct model for this**. I think I need 5 dummy variables:

- income1 and income2 are (0,0) for income=no info, (1,0) for income=high, (0,1) for income=low ;
- behavior = 0 for behavior=bad and 1 for behavior=good ;
- pers1 and pers2 are (0,0) for perspective=self, (1,0) for perspective=others, (0,1) for perspective=thirdperson.

Now, the model I came up with so far looks like this (for participant i, perspective j):

$y_{ij}=\beta_{0i}+\beta_{1i} \cdot pers1_{ij}+\beta_{2i} \cdot pers2_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}$

where:

$\beta_{0i} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01} \cdot income1_i + \gamma_{02} \cdot income2_i + \gamma_{03} \cdot behavior_i + \gamma_{04} \cdot income1_i \cdot behavior_i + \gamma_{05} \cdot income2_i \cdot behavior_i + \zeta_{0i}$

These intercepts refer to the values on Y when pers1 and pers2 are both 0 (thus when perspective = self). They depend on the interaction between income and behavior (between subjects factors) and a random component, $\zeta_{0i}$, which is the difference between (participant i's value for Y **when perspective = self**) and (participant i's cell mean of Y when perspective = self). **Is this interpretation correct? If so, do the $\zeta_{0i}$'s depend on which category of perspective I take as reference category?** Or does it refer to the difference between (average of Y over j perspectives within person i) and the (participant i's cell mean of these values) ?

I would then take:

$\beta_{1i} = \gamma_{10} + \gamma_{11} \cdot income1_i + \gamma_{12} \cdot income2_i + \gamma_{13} \cdot behavior_i + \gamma_{14} \cdot income1_i \cdot behavior_i + \gamma_{15} \cdot income2_i \cdot behavior_i$

and $\beta_{2i}$ analogously. Note that I do not include a random component here. My intuition says it does not make sense to include a random component (for participants) for the effect of, e.g., pers1 when there is only 1 observation per participant x perspective cell, **but I am not sure…** (I guess I also have just one observation for the intercepts, so the random component there probably follows the second interpretation I suggested?)

**How can I fit such a model in R?** (the data are structured such that I have three rows per person, each row referring to one perspective)

I tried: `lmer(liking ~ income1*behavior*pers1 + income1*behavior*pers2 + income2*behavior*pers1 + income2*behavior*pers2 + (1|subject))`

and it seems to give the output that I need, but I am sure if this is the right analysis.

Comments would be very much appreciated!